# Is "7:00 p.m., ..." correct?

Tags: capitalization

A poster reads something like:

> 7:30 p.m., Alexander Hall

How un-stylish or incorrect is that?  Is it actually incorrect to write "p.m." in lower case?

Comment: Looks fine to me. But I wouldn't trouble to put the dots after p and m.

Comment: It all comes down to whatever [style guide](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) is your standard for determining the stylishness or correctness of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a style issue. Different people write the acronyms for *post meridiem* and *ante meridiem* different ways. For instance, *Chicago Manual of Style* recommends "a.m." and "p.m.," but says these "sometimes appear as small capitals, with or without periods." [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/p-m-) also shows all four ways of writing the acronym as acceptable, but with "a.m."/"p.m." as the preferred.

You can basically write it however you wish unless you're told to follow a particular style guide's preferred capitalization/spelling.